# Question About Permalink in wordpress

Tags: permalinks

I have chosen single theme in Wordpress for website and onsite blog. I want to set permalink in two different way one for websites page(like abc.in/xyx) and other for onsite blog(like abc.in/blog/blogtitle), can it is possible. If Yes, Then please reply.

Thank You

Comment: are you using a plugin for the blog part?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set the permalink *Custom Structure* with the value `blog/%postname%/`

Answer (score 0):

You can set WordPress Blog Post Permalink to **example.com/this-is-a-permalink** using **%%postname%%**.

Go to **WordPress Dashboard> Permalinks**, and Select **"Post Name"** type Permalink and Save Your Changes.

You can also check this [Effective WordPress Permalink Setting Guide](https://theguidex.com/what-is-the-best-seo-friendly-url-structure-for-wordpress/)